GetAsyncKeyState, more "KeyHit" then "KeyDown" C++
I want to implement a key hit setup, I'm using GetAsyncKeyState to implement key down. which works a charm, but I'm struggling on how to implement a "hit." Imagine a game of space invaders, left arrow and right arrow move the ship, these are held down for continuous movement either way, but, you can only shoot one bullet at a time, you "hit" space, then to shoot again, you've got to release the space key, then press it again, keeping it down has no effect, hence, the "hit."
I've tried a few things, but for the life of me, I just cannot see the implementation, I was looking at something like this:
for (int loop = VM_LBUTTON; loop <= VK_OEM_CLEAR; loop++)
{
    SHORT keyState = GetAsyncKeyState(loop);
    if (keyState & 0x8000)
    {
        if (keyDownHitState[loop] == true) //The button has been pressed previously.
        {
            if (keyDownState[loop] == true) //Previously down, but perform "The hit"
            {
                keyDownHitState[loop] = false;
            }
            else
            {
                keyDownHitState[loop] = true;
            }
        }
        keyDownState[loop] = true;
    }
    else
    {
        keyDownState[loop] = false;
    }
}

I know the least significant bit of the return value could help, but it's deemed unreliable, so don't want to go there.
Like I said, the "key down" part is fine and does what I want (Obviously the easy bit), but I've tried all sorts of ways to get the hit bit working, and nope... It just won't have it!

if (key_hit(SPACE)) { if (can_shoot) { shoot(); can_shoot = false; } } else { can_shoot = true; }  Need a bit more logic if there is a "reload" of a minimum duration.

Is there a particular reason why you're querying the asynchronous key state (rather than the synchronous key state)?

@IInspectable Because as far as I'm aware, the function returns the state of the key[s] in the here and now, regardless of the event queue. Eljay, the space invaders example is just, an example, but what I'm trying to do is implement the logic that's behind the "key_hit" function you have there.

@IInspectable you can't use the synchronous key state unless there is a message loop receiving WM_KEY... window messages to update that key state.

@RemyLebeau Good point, and as such, I have tried to implement it via the window procedure checking wParam, the idea that you can get info that the same key was held down in the previous call temped me to go the GetAsyncKeyState way, and then I found it wasnt a safe bet. Regardless of where I get the state from and how, is another matter really, and not what I'm asking. What I have "looks" right, but isnt, one of them I've tried all sorts and in now in a muddle where I'm probably doing the same stuff again! :D

So, I went away from the keyboard, had myself a soak in the bath, came back... And cracked it within 15 minutes! :D I've edited the top post to show the difference... But basically, an extra array was the key.

@IInspectable Any particular reason the edit I made to the original post above which showed my solution to the problem? I'm all for people editing my stuff, but to wipe out something which works, without leaving a reason, is a bit... Rude!

I rolled back the edit as Stack Overflow is a Q&A site, not a forum. If you want to provide an answer to your question post an answer. The content isn't wiped, either. If you need to recall it, you can obtain it from the revision history.
